# PowerShell Azure Command Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault not returning anything

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-backup-vault

So I have a PowerShell Script, that works with an Service Principal, and tries to get all Recovery Service Vaults in a specific Subscription. Therefor the Service Principal has the following permission in Azure: 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/Vaults/read'. The Scope is the Subscription.

When I try to fetch the data from Azure with the following Command I dont get any result: `Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault`
With my Admin Account (Contributor rights), the Script, returns the Recovery Service Vaults. Also, when I use Azure Graph `Search-AzGraph -Query "Resources | where type =~ 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults'"`with the Service Principal I get the expected result, only issue seems to be that the `Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault` doesnt work.
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you receive empty results, it could be because you entered the wrong subscription details or that the subscription you selected did not include any recovery service vaults.

*Check below to resolve the issue:*

1. Try clearing the token cache with  `Clear-AzContext -Force` command once you logged into the account using `Connect-AzAccount`.
2. Before retrieving the results, set the required subscription ID context with below command.

```
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "xxx"
```

3. Also check that the Service Principal have the required vault or resource group level permissions. At the resource group level, where the Recovery Services vault is located, assign the `Reader` role to the Service Principal and `Backup Operator` role at the vault level to the Service Principal.

[image]

After checking all the above, I tried retrieving the expected results with
`Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault` command and was successful as shown.

[image]

Comment: Do I need the Backup Operator Role, or can it also work with Backup Reader as I just want to get the data, not edit anything?

Comment: If you are allowed to give `Back up operator` role then it would be suitable for all types of operations. Or else proving `Back up reader` also works in this case.  @flaf

Comment: The Service Principal has all the following rights now:
`Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read`, `Microsoft.RecoveryServices/Vaults/read`, `Microsoft.RecoveryServices/Locations/backupStatus/action`, `Microsoft.RecoveryServices/Vaults/backupProtectionContainers/read`, `Microsoft.RecoveryServices/Vaults/backupProtectedItems/read`, `Microsoft.DataProtection/backupVaults/backupinstances/recoveryPoints/read` all are on scope of the Subscription the Vaults are in, still getting no result, tho when I try `Get-AzVM` I get the VMs back...

Comment: Have you tried to retrieve vaults from one resource group? @flaf

Comment: Weirdly that seems to work, but I need the Vaults of the entire Subscription not only one single Resourcegroup...

Comment: Have you enabled all the roles properly? Can you cross check once again! @flaf

Comment: The JSON of the CustomRole, Scope on Subscription states the following permissions on "actions":
`"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read",
"Microsoft.RecoveryServices/Vaults/read",
"Microsoft.RecoveryServices/Locations/backupStatus/action",
"Microsoft.RecoveryServices/Vaults/backupProtectionContainers/read",
"Microsoft.RecoveryServices/Vaults/backupProtectedItems/read",
"Microsoft.DataProtection/backupVaults/backupInstances/recoveryPoints/read"`


With nothing in "notActions", "dataActions" and "notDataActions", should be assigned properly...

Comment: Can you check if any network or firewall is blocking you to retrieving you the results? @flaf

Comment: Just checked, nothing gets blocked from any firewall...

Comment: Can you also check what are the roles and permissions you have provided at vault level? @flaf

Comment: Nevermind, I just added the Reader Role on ResourceGroup Scope to the Service Principal, now it works, weird that I need that but whatever... Thanks for your help!